# How can this Xcode Clang static analyzer warning be suppressed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, warnings, clang

> "Potential leak of an object allocated on line *n* and stored into '*variable*'."

Normally this is a very helpful analyzer warning, but there are a few situations where I get annoying false positives that I would like to suppress to keep my analyzer results clean. In the analyzer's defense, what it's noticing would definitely be a memory leak were it not for a release in another path of execution (to which it is blind).

I'll elaborate on my situation. It happens in various flavors, but the general pattern is as follows:

1. An object is allocated and its delegate is set.
2. Something is done with the object. (A task started, a view displayed, etc).
3. Execution of current method ends. (Enter Clang warning).
4. Object decides its task is complete, sends delegate a message.
5. Delegate releases object.

This is not at all an esoteric design pattern, so I'm hoping suppression is possible.  I know it can be avoided by storing the offending object in an ivar that is later released, but I greatly prefer to not add ivar pollution.

Comment: It strikes me as odd that an object's delegate retains it. Typically, an object retains it's delegate, and to have the delegate retain the object would make a retain cycle. I'm not saying there are ZERO cases where a delegate might want to retain (perhaps short-lived) the object, but it would seem relevant to know why that's the case here.  From what's been said here, I'd say it's more kosher for the object to retain itself for the duration of the operation and subsequent delegate message than for the delegate to "take ownership of" the alloc/init implied retain.

Comment: @ipmcc: While it is possible for an object to retain its delegate, and there are a few places in SDK where a class does just that, I would say it is more common to store a delegate as a weak reference, to avoid the retain cycle you mention. Either way, it is definitely not "typical" for an object to retain its delegate. In my case, some class created an object with alloc/init and and set itself as the delegate. As the owner of the class, the delegate later releases the object when the it is done. There is no contrived ownership happening here.

Comment: @ipmcc - Matt is correct, the normal pattern is: Object A creates Object B and sets itself as Object B's delegate.  Object A retains Object B.  When Object A gets dealloced, it makes sure to unset itself as Object B's delegate, otherwise you may crash.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda misspoke here. Matt Wilding and DougW's comments are right for most cases. That said, there exists the potential for odd cases, and anything can retain anything else -- there's no enforcement of retain/release behaviors in the delegate pattern.

Comment: @ipmcc - Very true, and you should always "trust but verify".  I had a long discussion at WWDC last year with an Apple dev because UIView's setAnimationDelegate actually retains the delegate and, at the time, did not say so (and there's no way to unset it).  He didn't seem to think that was a big deal, but I noticed the docs have since been updated, so apparently someone did.

Answer (score 6):

Clang has a few new [Source Annotations](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html). In specific, you may be interested in the [ns_consumed](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html#attr_ns_consumed) attribute.

Comment: This seems to be just what I'm looking for, however attribute_ns_consumed does not appear to be available: __has_feature(attribute_ns_consumed) returns false. The documentation you site specifically calls them Mac OS X API Annotations. Are these not available on iOS?

Comment: The naming is a bit misleading, it actually means Cocoa API Annotations. And `ns_consumed` is rather new. I don't think Clang 1.6 has them (the version shipped with Xcode 3.2), but I would hope Clang 2.0 does (I haven't tested).

Comment: You could try installing [checker-254](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), which is the latest version of the static analyzer. There's even a script in that download which will make Xcode use it for static analyzing instead of the built-in version.

Comment: I installed the new analyzer and still no dice on the source annotations.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - While this is good advice for some cases, I'm voting it down because it is most definitely not appropriate here.  There is something incorrect about his retain/release cycle that should be fixed, not suppressed.

Comment: @DougW: What makes you say that? The OP explicitly said it's a false positive, and that he's ensuring the object gets released through another execution path. Yes, it's probably indicative of poor architecture, and it's quite possible that he hasn't thought this through and it's possible that a particular case could lead to the object being leaked, but you don't have his code and you don't know that this is, in fact, the case.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - He *thinks* it's a false positive because he releases the object once he gets a delegate callback from it.  If he has very carefully architected his object lifecycle, he most likely will get that callback before being himself dealloced, but there's a lot of ways that could accidentally happen first (low memory?).  The object he created will then have an invalid delegate pointer and crash the app.  I've done this a thousand times and there's no safe way to set yourself as an unretained delegate to an object without also retaining that object and *unsetting* yourself in dealloc.

Comment: @DougW: This addresses the problem posed. Whether my architecture is a complete failure is not really related to this answer's validity; others may find a valid situation in the future where they also need to suppress the warning, and this answer is just as valid as any.

Comment: @Matt Wilding - It answers the literal question you posed, but the question you posed was predicated upon invalid assumptions.  You presumed that this warning was a false positive, and it is not.  Like I said, Kevin's answer is technically correct, but most people are interested in the overall correct solution to their problem.

Comment: @DougW: You're still insisting that it's not a false positive, and you *cannot* possibly know that without seeing the code. It's entirely possible that Matt has managed to ensure that his object cannot be dealloc'd before the delegate message is received. Yes, there's a good chance you're actually right, but you're stating something as fact which is only supposition.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - Sure Kevin, you're right.  Technically I can't know for sure what he's doing.  But it's like someone coming into a car mechanic and saying "Hey, my car is making a loud thumping sound, I'm positive it's the windshield wiper fluid, can you tell me how to change it?"  Yeah, you could just tell him how to replace the fluid and be technically correct.  All I'm saying is that a good mechanic would generally mention that there's a chance that's not the real problem.  I'm not trying to challenge your correctness, I'm just saying there's sometimes more to it than that.

Comment: @Matt Wilding - I would also just add that, even though I disagree, if you really feel that this is the answer to your question you ought to mark it and give Kevin credit.

Comment: @DougW - I would have done so, but unfortunately it only works with a version of Clang that is newer than my own.

Comment: @Matt: You can download a newer version of the [analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/installation.html) and it even comes with a script that will "install" it into Xcode, so Xcode will use your newer version when you invoke the static analyzer.

Comment: @Kevin: The last version I "installed" into Xcode does appear to be a few versions older than the newest one at this point. I'll make it a point to try again in the near future at some point when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should heed the static analyser message in this case.  Your pattern has potential problems.

Specifically, when you return from the method invoked to do step 5, you are in a method of an object that may already have been deallocated.  I interpret your pattern something like this:

```
// steps 1, 2, 3
-(void) methodThatCreatesObject
{
    id theObj = [[TheObj alloc] init];
    [theObj setDelegate: delegateObj];
    // other stuff
}
```

Note the above breaches the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

```
// step 4 - a method of theObj
-(void) someMethod
{
    [delegate notifyTaskCompleteFromObj: self];
    // self points to an invalid object here.  Doing anything with self results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

The above breaches an assumption stated in the memory management rules:

> A received object is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the method it was received in

if we say `self` is a received object, which it is technically, since it is passed as a parameter on the stack.

```
// step 5 the delegate method defined in the delegate object

-(void) notifyTaskCompleteFromObj: (TheObj*) anObj
{
    // do stuff
    [anObj release];
}
```

The above also breaches the memory management rules.

The normal pattern is to have a controller that owns both the delegate and the object that has the delegate (often the controller is itself the delegate).  I think you should move to that pattern.

Comment: If that were my pattern, I would agree with you. I suppose my generalization left too much room for interpretation. Here's a specific example of exactly what's going on: In a method of a controller object, another object (A custom network request) is allocated, and it's delegate is set to self, not another object. So the controller owns the object to which it is acting as delegate. Later, upon receiving a notification from the network request, the controller releases the request. There is no breach; I'm not handing off responsibility to another object.

Comment: @Matt: Are you saying that `theObj` in my example is an instance variable?

Comment: No, it's not. I could keep a reference to it as an ivar to release it later, but since the theObj passes a reference to itself in the delegate message, I elect to release the reference passed as a parameter of the message rather than add an ivar just to release it. The lack of reference to theObj is exactly what the analyzer doesn't like though.

Comment: @Matt Wilding - Jeremy is correct here.  Just because you theoretically balance out your retains/releases at a later time when a delegate may or may not call back does not make it correct usage.  You need to balance retain/release counts by the end of every scope you create.  You should never leave a method scope without a balanced retain/release count for every object used (taking autoreleases into account), unless you are in a method that explicitly returns an object to be owned by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting option here occurred to me. The OP gave the following scenario:

1. An object is allocated and its delegate is set.
2. Something is done with the object. (A task started, a view displayed, etc).
3. Execution of current method ends. (Enter Clang warning).
4. Object decides its task is complete, sends delegate a message.
5. Delegate releases object.

If, instead of an explicit release, you merely wanted to extend the lifetime of the allocated object to that of the allocating/delegeate object, you could to this:

```
TheObject* foo = [[TheObject alloc] init] autorelease];
foo.delegate = self;
[foo doSomething];
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, foo, foo, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
return;
```

By setting foo as an associated object with the retain policy, the delegate (self) will effectively take a retain on the object which will be subsequently released whenever the delegate(self) is dealloced (later).

It's not EXACTLY what the OP asked for, but it's a useful pattern nonetheless, and feels like it would probably suffice in the situation the OP presented.